# Using COUNTIF for non-adjacent cells

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a table listing various statistics for a given category over a number of years.  Below is an example:

```
         |          2016         |          2017         |
Category | Stat1 | Stat2 | Stat3 | Stat1 | Stat2 | Stat3 |
   Cat1  |   2   |   4   |   4   |   6   |   3   |   3   |
```

I want to analyze each statistic over time.  Specifically, I want to count the number of years each statistic was greater than a given value.  Now, I know I can use `COUNTIF` for a cell range, but in my table the pertinent cells are not adjacent. I also know I could rearrange the table, but I'd like to avoid that if I could. Is it possible to execute a similar function over a number of non-adjacent cells?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A series (pair in the example) of COUNTIFs might be added together but perhaps easier with [COUNTIFS](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/COUNTIFS_function). For example, with cutoffs chosen in M3:M9 and the stats named in N2:P2:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$3:$G$3,">"&$M3,$B$2:$G$2,N$2)
```

copied across and down to suit.

[image: COUNTIFS table example]